# Facebook - "openID" danger?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph

I am scared that someone can get into anybodys account on my game, if user does not have Facebook. Stealer makes facebook with same email that user in my game, and then click "Login with facebook" -> redirects him to permission page -> back to my page - it detects that facebook email is same as victim's and -> stealer is logged into victims account.

How could I prevent this? Just t allow LOGGED in users to associate their account with facebook's ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenID requires the user to be logged into the website of the OpenID account they are using. So unless someone is logged into that Facebook account, Facebook won't authenticate them and allow them to be logged into your website. So if someone uses the same email address as another person's Facebook account they will still fail to login.

**Update**

Facebook does require the verification of email addresses so this kind of hijacking attempt will not work.

Comment: sorry, by "openID" I meant ALL services which provides fast-login API. So, I'm talking about facebook only

Comment: My answer applies to *any* OpenID provider, including Facebook.

Comment: I didn'T get it. Facebook requires logged to be facebook account, right? But when comeone creates fake account with same email as registered in my DB, he would be able to log in. Or ?

Comment: If someone creates a fake account with the same email they would *not* be able to login. Just having the same email address is not enough. They must also log into Facebook *successfully* to pass the OpenID authentication. Obviously they won't know the Facebook password for that account and thus will fail authentication and will *not* be logged into your website.

Comment: I think you didn'T get me. Example: You're my victim, you do not have facebook and I know your mail is foo@bar.com (on my site) -> I will create facebook account -> mail foo@bar.com -> does facebook require activate? (maybe that's the point) -> if no, login to facebook -> go to my one-click login app -> user is logged on my email .. so, does facebook require activation?

Comment: Facebook will not allow the same email address to be used with two accounts.

Comment: `You're my victim, you do not have facebook`, `you do not have facebook` ! but victim has same email on my game account as my fake FB account has!

Comment: If they don't have Facebook then they can't use Facebook's OpenID.

Comment: AAH. Imagine, I want to steal your game account. You have accounts on :Game, You do not have accounts on: facebook, so your email is NOT registered on facebook but is on my game. I know that you have got email: foo@bar.com (registeration email for my game) with account name "vicitim". I decide to steal your game account. I found that game has option to login via facebook and I also know that you do NOT have facebook account. I am going to create facebook account with YOUR email. It means that both, YOURS game account and MY facebook acount (with your email) .....

Comment: ... have same email addresses! So I can login as you into game! Do you got it ?

Comment: Let me put it this way: if this was possible OpenID would not exist. What you're imagining cannot be done. OpenID is safe.

Comment: Don't you anyone remember if you had to activate your account via email or not ?

Comment: Facebook does require users to verify their email address

Comment: That's the point! I think that openID and all similar services does require it too. Please put is as answer so I can accept it

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly.